# PHP 7.3 Function create_function() is deprecated-

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I have used create_function in my wordpress theme below.

```
add_filter('document_title_separator', create_function('', 'return "|";'));
```

and

```
add_filter('the_generator', create_function('', 'return "";'));
```

But for PHP 7.3, the create_function() is deprecated.

Any idea, how to fix my codes above on PHP 7.3.

Thanks for your help,

I  tried this  but it doesn't work :

```
add_filter('document_title_separator', function() {return |;});
```

and

```
add_filter('the_generator', function() {return ;'});
```

Comment: It worked for me using the answer of @Shalior
Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

there are syntax errors in your code
try these:

```
add_filter('document_title_separator', function() {return '|';});
```

and

```
add_filter('the_generator', function() {return ;});
```

and you can always use the traditional way like this

```
add_filter('the_generator' , 'my_generator_function');
function my_generator_function(){
    return;
}
```

tip: use an IDE that notifies you when making syntax errors

Comment: Thank you so much,  it worked very well for me ! you're the best :)